# "Request format is invalid"

Tags: c#, objective-c, http, webserver, webmethod

When trying to connect to the following web method, "Request format is invalid" is returned:

```
public string myWebMethod(string test)
{
    return "connected";
}
```

This is the objective C code:

```
NSString *seshID = @"test-session";       
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=%@", seshID];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSString *comparisonURLString = SERVER_COMPARE_URL_STRING;
NSURL *comparisonURL = [NSURL URLWithString: comparisonURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:comparisonURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSLog(response);
```

However, if I alter the web method so that it takes no parameters:

```
public string myWebMethod()
```

And change the corresponding line in my obj-c code to:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
```

It works, with the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">connected</string>
```

Can anyone explain why the latter seems to work but the former doesn't? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried fiddler to iron out any webservice issues?

Comment: @all:
Turns out I was missing a line: `[request setHTTPBody:postData];` 
Mea culpa and thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: @Jon: I'm not very familiar with Fiddler but am having a look at Fiddler2 now. Cheers for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a similar problem between JAVA WebMethod and C#. The problem was resolved by creating a class string1 inherant from SoapHeader and containing a string[].

Then for your example, you can try this

```
public string myWebMethod(string[] test)
{
    return "connected";
}
```

or

```
public string myWebMethod(char[] test)
{
    return "connected";
}
```

You can check too with Fiddler what kind of data is really passed.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I was missing a line of code but I'll accept this as the answer as it could help someone else..